# How to use the props to handle changes in RSuite.js component framework?

Tags: reactjs

Apologies for the silliness, but I am a beginner in React and am trying to understand how I can use the props allowed in the components in the RSuitejs component framework.

I am trying to understand what this does:

`(value: any, event: SyntheticInputEvent) => void`

I found it here: https://rsuitejs.com/en/components/input#Props

What I am trying to achieve is to fire a function when a user inputs something.

I really appreciate for even looking at this.

```
/* this is my index.js file rendering to index.html */
/* this code assumes you have imported the rsuitejs components */

class App extends React.Component {
  Daynight(props) {
    if (Toggle.onChange) {
      return <p>Success is not {props.pronoun}</p>;
    }
    return <p>Success is {props.pronoun}</p>;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" style={{ margin: `${30}px` }}>
        <Input
          style={({ width: 300 }, { marginBottom: `${30}px` })}
          placeholder="Your Name Here Please!"
        />
        <Button appearance="primary"> Hello world </Button>
        <this.Daynight pronoun="yours" />
        <Header />
        <Divider>Hello World!</Divider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So the final result would be, if I input my name in the box, it should render it in the `Daynight` function instead of the `pronoun`.

Comment: please look at the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This results in creating new `Daylight` function for each `App` instance, which is not very efficient way of doing this.
The former shouldn't be defined as instance method of the latter. It could be just:

An `onChange` event handler returns a `Synthetic Event` object which contains useful meta data such as the target input’s **id, name, and current value**.

React creates a `SyntheticEvent` for each event. It has been passed into event handlers or callback functions and contains details of the event. 
Just like  has event handler props :  `(checked: boolean, event: SyntheticEvent) => void` which means you will get `boolean` value when you toggle the `<Toggle />` component.

some of the synthetic events:

```
    bubbles: boolean
    cancelable: boolean
    currentTarget: DOMEventTarget
    defaultPrevented: boolean
    eventPhase: number
    isTrusted: boolean
    nativeEvent: DOMEvent
    preventDefault(): void
    isDefaultPrevented(): boolean
    stopPropagation(): void
    isPropagationStopped(): boolean
    target: DOMEventTarget
    timeStamp: number
    type: string
```

here is a demo : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-svnpc

```
import { Toggle } from 'rsuite';

class Daynight extends React.Component {
  state = {
    success: false
  };
  change = e => {
    this.setState({ success: e });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Toggle onChange={this.change} />
        {this.state.success ? (
          <p>{this.props.pronoun} is success</p>
        ) : (
          <p> {this.props.pronoun} is no success</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" style={{ margin: `${30}px` }}>
        <Input
          style={({ width: 300 }, { marginBottom: `${30}px` })}
          placeholder="Your Name Here Please!"
        />
        <Button appearance="primary"> Hello world </Button>
        <Daynight pronoun="yours" />
        <Header />
        <Divider>Hello World!</Divider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you very much!